# Mockito mock Java @Value with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

Hi I have this simple code for my Spring Boot Project:

```java
@Component
public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
    @Value("${bug.value}")
    private String id;
    @Value("${wrong.value}")
    private String userName;

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return User.builder()
                .id(rs.getInt(id))
                .userName(rs.getString(userName)).build();
    }
}
```

what I want is to create a simple Mockito Test that will check @Value strings like so:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserRowMapperTest {
    @Mock
    Environment environment;
    @Mock
    ResultSet resultSet;
    @InjectMocks
    UserRowMapper userRowMapper;

    @Test
    void testMapRow() {
        when(environment.getProperty("user.id")).thenReturn("id");
        when(environment.getProperty("user.userName")).thenReturn("userName");
        try {
            final User user = userRowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, anyInt());
            
            // check if its ok
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't find a simple way to check if the value I injected is what I expect.

any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there is no mocking mechanism for Spring's `@Value`. However, you can use a simple workaround using [`ReflectionUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) that serves for this purpose according to the JavaDoc:

> ReflectionTestUtils is a collection of reflection-based utility methods for use in unit and integration testing scenarios.
>
> There are often times when it would be beneficial to be able to set a non-public field, invoke a non-public setter method, or invoke a non-public configuration or lifecycle callback method when testing code involving

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userRowMapper, "id", "my-id-value");
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userRowMapper, "userName", "my-userName-value");
```

JavaDoc for [`ReflectionTestUtils#setField(Object, String, Object)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Hi Nikolas, as I understand that using ReflectionTestUtils is a bad practice.

Comment: Reflection and OOP principles are not friends, I know. Using `ReflectionTestUtils` is a common practice for setting `@Value` properties. Alternatively, you might want to create a full-args constructor to pass the mocks and String properties through.

Answer (score 0):

Add `getter` methods for `id` and `userName` fields instead of mocking `Environment` class.

```
@Component
public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
    @Value("${bug.value}")
    private String id;

    @Value("${wrong.value}")
    private String userName;

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return User.builder()
                .id(rs.getInt(getId()))
                .userName(rs.getString(getUserName())).build();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

While mocking:

```
Mockito.when(userRowMapper.getId()).thenReturn("id");
Mockito.when(userRowMapper.getUserName()).thenReturn("userName");
```

---

Also, you can use `TestPropertySource` annotation to provide altogether different properties file:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/application2.properties")
public class TestClassTest {

    @Autowired
    TestClass testClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("id", testClass.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: `userRowMapper` is under test, it's not a mock, exception will be thrown due to `Mockito.when(userRowMapper.getId()).thenReturn("id");`

Comment: the problem with your approach is that it's not a unit test anymore when you use @SpringBootTest annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to you to do not use inline `@Value` annotation on the consumer class. As you have seen, the class testability decreases.

You can solve your problem simply creating a `@Configuration` bean and injecting it to the `UserRowMapper` class. In this way, using DI you can easily mock the configuration in your tests.

See below a naïve implementation.

```
@Configuration
public class UserRowMapperConfiguration {
    @Value("${bug.value}")
    private String id;

    @Value("${wrong.value}")
    private String userName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
    
    private UserRowMapperConfiguration configuration;
    
    public UserRowMapper (UserRowMapperConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return User.builder()
                .id(rs.getInt(this.configuration.getId()))
                .userName(rs.getString(this.configuration.getUserName())).build();
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserRowMapperTest {
    @Mock
    UserRowMapperConfiguration configuration;
    @Mock
    ResultSet resultSet;
    @InjectMocks
    UserRowMapper userRowMapper;

    @Test
    void testMapRow() {
        when(configuration.getId()).thenReturn("id");
        when(configuration.getUserName()).thenReturn("userName");
        try {
            final User user = userRowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, anyInt());
            
            // check if its ok
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, the problem is that when you add a configuration class, it becomes really hard to understand what properties can be used in `UserRowMapper` without changing classes but maybe its the best cource of action but it doesn't solve the problem with checking if user written a Value parameter by mistake

Comment: @AndreyKishtov I did not catch your point :-)

Comment: i meant that when you move the code from UserRowMapper to UserMapperConfiguration it will be harder to spot a mistake, my main goal was to see if someone made a mistake in     @Value("${bug.value}")
and now the mistake can't even be seen

Comment: Actually, the UserRowMapperConfiguration class I wrote does not contain any logic, it is just a container for all the configuration values that could be used by the UserRowMapper class.

Answer (score 0):

As *thepaoloboi* suggested use a configuration class to hold all your configs.
Now to test that your config is pointing to the right @Value key, you create an integration test by simply loading that object using spring without loading the whole context. That way it'll be as fast as a unit test.

Here's an example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(UserRowMapperConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "user.id=id" , "user.userName=userName"})
class UserRowMapperConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRowMapperConfiguration userRowMapperConfiguration;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals("id",userRowMapperConfiguration.getId());
        assertEquals("userName",userRowMapperConfiguration.getUserName());
    }
}
```

and Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class UserRowMapperConfiguration {
    @Value("${bug.value}")
    private String id;

    @Value("${wrong.value}")    
    private String userName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockito cannot inject primitives, wrappers (Integer, Long, ...) or Strings, so @InjectMocks is not an option unless you refactor those fields to a different object and mock that object as @thepaoloboi suggested.

In any case, field injection provides really bad testability so the best option would be to use constructor injection as seen below:

```
@Component
public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    private final String id;
    private final String userName;

    public UserRowMapper(@Value("${bug.value}") String id, @Value("${wrong.value}") String userName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return User.builder()
                .id(rs.getInt(id))
                .userName(rs.getString(userName)).build();
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserRowMapperTest {

    private final String mockId = "id";
    private final String mockUserName = "userName";

    @Mock
    private ResultSet resultSet;
    private UserRowMapper userRowMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        userRowMapper = new UserRowMapper(mockId, mockUserName);
    }

    @Test
    void testMapRow() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service
public class PreComputeService {

    @Autowired
    LoadData loadData;

    @Autowired
    PreComputeHelper preComputeHelper;
    @Autowired
    CalculationService calculationService;
    @Autowired
    DataPointRepository dataPointRepository;

    @Value("${hds.email.host}")
    String environment;  // property we are using from application.properties 
   
  // do some stuff 

}




@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    class PreComputeServiceTest {
        @Spy
        @InjectMocks
        PreComputeService preComputeService;
    
        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
            preComputeService.environment ="Dev";
        }
       // some test cases 
    
    }
```